# apache rewrite POST request SSL https mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl, https

I am using secure https for checkout and viewing the cart, while the front end of the store where the products are is not secure - standard http. The transfer from http to https achieved via the following rules:

```
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|jpe|png|css|js)$ - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^/(checkout|customer|sales|wishlist)/(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

All work correctly for a while now, the problem is when adding a product to the cart the post variable with quantity of product gets dropped. If I remove the rewrite rule the /checkout/ url becomes insecure and the quantity gets there OK.
I can add the apache access logs on here to show what happens with https on and https off – basically with no redirect there is one POST and one GET request, while with the redirect there is one POST and a whole lot of GETs.

The question is for the Apache mod_rewrite experts – is there something special I need to do in addition to the rules that I already have to get the POST content delivered to where it is going?

Here are the access logs:

/* HTTP */

```
121.99.xxx.xxx - - [22/Feb/2014:08:48:28 +0400] "POST /checkout/cart/xxx.xxx/ HTTP/1.1" 302 567 "http://pacifika.ru/checkout/cart/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36"
121.99.xxx.xxx - - [22/Feb/2014:08:48:29 +0400] "GET /checkout/cart/ HTTP/1.1" 200 25465 "http://pacifika.ru/checkout/cart/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36"
```

/* HTTPS */

```
121.99.xxx.xxx - - [22/Feb/2014:08:50:53 +0400] "POST /checkout/cart/xxx.xxx/ HTTP/1.1" 302 502 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36"
121.99.xxx.xxx - - [22/Feb/2014:08:50:54 +0400] "GET /checkout/cart/xxx.xxx/ HTTP/1.1" 302 820 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36"
121.99.xxx.xxx - - [22/Feb/2014:08:50:54 +0400] "GET /checkout/cart/ HTTP/1.1" 302 482 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36"
121.99.xxx.xxx - - [22/Feb/2014:08:50:55 +0400] "GET /checkout/cart/ HTTP/1.1" 200 25563 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Could you post an example of the URL where this rule is not working?

Comment: Here are the access logs showing what happens first during non secure add to cart click (rewrite rules commented out), second with the rewrite to https rule enabled.

Comment: Anybody? Someone must know more about redirects and POST requests? I think something weird going on with the log below, since https enabled seem to generate 3 redirect 302 requests before settling on 200, while http only does one 302...

Answer (score 2):

Solved it, Here is one more rule I had to add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST$
```

That made the problem go away :)